# Responsive column based table rather than row based

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, css-grid

tl;dr is there a way to align rows of a list of column objects in CSS?

I have a bunch of objects with properties that I want to show as separate elements on the page, however I want their properties to align together like a table.
A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

All the cells should align vertically, however the objects are defined as columns rather than rows.

Is there a way to achieve this with HTML/CSS?

The only way I could think of so far is to split the data, so the first property of all objects is defined in a row of cells, and the second property would be the second row, etc., with some padding between the columns. However that requires very messy code (JSX in this case) to populate the cells, such as a loop per property, and I am not sure if it can handle wrapping on overflow and such like modern grids/flexboxes can.

Comment: Subgrid could be useful for this (note* not fully supported across all browsers). An example of what you seem to want is here: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/what-are-css-subgrids

Comment: @Adam that is precisely what I want, including the example, thank you! I would still love knowing other solutions since it is not yet very much supported as you noted

Comment: As I appear to have misunderstood, I thought you wanted to output the whole of one object before moving to another, could you put some code into your question which shows a list of typical objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

display: contents helps here, but check on caniuse.com that some feature you want in your real life example is properly implemented.

Here's a simple 3 column (=3 'object') example:

```css
.objects {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
}

.objects>* {
  display: contents;
}

.objects>*>* {
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.objects>div>div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.objects>div>div:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="objects">
  <div>
    <div>1<br>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>2<br>2</div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ohh yes. I like this!

Comment: This is what I meant by splitting the properties into their own lines. It's possible, but quite a pain to generate this HTML from a list of objects.

Comment: I must have misunderstood. I thought you had 3 objects in your example and you put one whole object out before moving to the next one, thus avoiding the need to think about rows at all.

Comment: That is true, however each object is a column rather than a row. What I would have liked is some element like <tc> instead of <tr> for a column based table (or a grid or whatever works), but there's no such thing.

Comment: Sorry, I am lost as to what you want. In my code one object is output, then the next and so on. Because of the grid each object occupies one column of the grid. What is missing?

Comment: I am confused. When I run the code snippet I see object 1 in the first row, object 2 in the second, and 3 in the third. Given the HTML above, all the 1's should be in the 1st column, all 2's in the 2nd column, and all 3's in the 3rd.

Comment: That's really weird, I was seeing each object in its own column. What has changed? I'll investigate.

Comment: Hmm, no wonder you didn't like it! I am confused as to what happened as I definitely saw them vertically in my own code. Something must have been slipped out of the CSS when I made it a snippet. I have put in a patch, but am uncertain it's the best way to go. Depends on how general you need the solution to be. Anyway each object is now displayed in a column of its own and the rows match across objects.

Comment: This is an interesting solution for one row of objects, it does seem to essentially have the same result as using subgrid, but is also supported by all major browsers (with caveats). I am starting to realize what I actually want which is the same behavior of flex's wrap is just not possible together with aligning rows. Both answers give solutions, but I'll mark this as the answer because it has wider support for now. Thanks for taking your time and updating your answer

Answer (score 1):

As per my commment above, subgrid would be ideal for this because, quite often, you wrap these comments in `divs`. However if you're prepared to forgo wrapper divs you can replicate this just using grid itself by using grid-template-rows to control the height and using grid-auto-flow to set up a column-based layout. See an example of the code below.

See [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) for a good primer on grid and this [video](https://youtu.be/rg7Fvvl3taU) from Kevin Powell. Also this [video](https://youtu.be/UwV4LtO0nHo) for subgrid.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  
  /* fill by columns, not rows (which is the default */
  grid-auto-flow: column; 
  
  /* set up each row so that it fits the content but the bottom one has to be at least 100px so it looks like your example*/
  grid-template-rows: max-content max-content minmax(100px, max-content); 
  
  /* equally space each column */
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr; 
}


/* the CSS below is just prettification, not really relevant to the problem you're having */
.container > div {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.header {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom-color: red;
}

.body {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom-color:red;
}

.footer {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Some Text</div>
  <div class="body">Some other<br>text</div>
  <div class="footer"></div>

  <div class="header">Some longer text</div>
  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="footer">Some other comment</div>

  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

**Edited to add**

For any number of rows, use CSS custom properties and set that property in the style attribute of the parent wrapper

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  
  /* fill by columns, not rows (which is the default */
  grid-auto-flow: column; 
  
  /* set up each row so that it fits the content but the bottom one has to be at least 100px so it looks like your example*/
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--num-rows), max-content); 
  
  /* equally space each column */
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr; 
}


/* the CSS below is just prettification, not really relevant to the problem you're having */
.container > div {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.header {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom-color: red;
}

.body, .extra-body {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom-color:red;
}

.footer {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style='--num-rows:3;'><!-- you can use JS to drop the number of rows here -->
  <div class="header">Some Text</div>
  <div class="body">Some other<br>text</div>
  <div class="footer"></div>

  <div class="header">Some longer text</div>
  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="footer">Some other comment</div>

  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>

<p>4 row example</p>
<div class="container" style='--num-rows:4;'><!-- you can use JS to drop the number of rows here -->
  <div class="header">Some Text</div>
  <div class="body">Some other<br>text</div>
  <div class='extra-body'>here</div>
  <div class="footer"></div>

  <div class="header">Some longer text</div>
  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class='extra-body'></div>
  <div class="footer">Some other comment</div>

  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class='extra-body'>here</div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the creative thinking. I am assuming there won't be a way to make this work for N rows, right? even a single row is useful to me, but what I really want is to have a flexible grid of objects that can wrap based on the available space. I might have to handle this by giving the cells explicit sizes so they match and ensure the content will never be bigger, until subgrid is properly supported

Comment: You have to know the number of rows in advance as you have to define grid-template-rows but you can use css custom properties then change that value by applying that value in the style attribute in the parent containing div.

Comment: Excuse me, I wasn't clear enough - I meant N rows of objects. Let's say the browser width gets too low to contain the existing columns, the desired behavior is that of flexbox's wrap property, a new line of objects should be formed, but since in this case the lines are the properties I am not sure if that's possible

Comment: Normally you'd use `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(...))` but this doesn't work well when `grid-auto-flow` is set to column. So I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Yeah figured as much, that's a shame. Thank you for the answer and information though, it will be useful for me in the future